# How do I add a CAFile to our certificates

Tags: http, go, server, x509certificate, ca

We are using a web server in a docker container. At the moment our public private key is working fine. The problem we have is that our CAFile is not being included as an offered certificate when we test our site with https://www.ssllabs.com/. After reviewing solutions, I attempted to add the certification to a caCertPool and added it to the configutation. Even after doing that, SSL Labs still says it does not see it and we still get a B Score. Here is a code snippet of what I am attempting without luck so far.

```
certs, err := newStaticCerts(&static.Config{UseStaticFiles: cfg.IsProduction, FallbackToDisk: true, AbsPkgPath: getMessagePath()})
        if err != nil {
            log.WithFields(log.F("error", err)).Fatal("Issue initializing static certs")
        }

        httpKey, err := certs.ReadFile("/certs/website.com.key")
        if err != nil {
            log.WithFields(log.F("error", err)).Fatal("Issue loading tls key")
        }

        httpPem, err := certs.ReadFile("/certs/website.com.pem")
        if err != nil {
            log.WithFields(log.F("error", err)).Fatal("Issue loading tls pem")
        }

        caFilePem, err := certs.ReadFile("/certs/CAFile.pem")
        if log.CheckErr(err, "Issue loading CAFile pem") {
            return
        }

        // Load client cert
        cert, err := tls.X509KeyPair(httpPem, httpKey)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        caCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
        caCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(caFilePem)

        tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
            MinVersion:               tls.VersionTLS12,
            CurvePreferences:         []tls.CurveID{tls.CurveP521, tls.CurveP384, tls.CurveP256},
            PreferServerCipherSuites: true,
            CipherSuites: []uint16{
                tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
                tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
            },
            Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
            RootCAs:      caCertPool,
        }

        tlsConfig.BuildNameToCertificate()

        //server := &http.Server{Addr: ":" + strconv.Itoa(cfg.AppPort), Handler: p.Serve(), TLSConfig: tlsConfig}
        srv := &http.Server{
            Addr:         ":" + strconv.Itoa(cfg.AppPort),
            Handler:      p.Serve(),
            TLSConfig:    tlsConfig,
            TLSNextProto: make(map[string]func(*http.Server, *tls.Conn, http.Handler), 0),
        }

        err = kmshttp.RunServer(srv)
        if log.CheckErr(err, "shutting down server") {
            return
        }
```

The problem is when we check our Certification Paths, our RSA CA 
is an "Extra download" and not included on our site.

Answer (score 0):

From the [tls.Config documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config):

> Certificates contains one or more certificate **chains** to present to the other side of the connection.
>
> [...]
>
> RootCAs defines the set of root certificate authorities that **clients** use when verifying server certificates.

The `RootCAs` field does nothing for servers. You only need to set the complete certificate chain in the `Certificates` field (excluding the root CA; that wouldn't technically break anything but waste bandwidth).

You haven't shown what `certs.ReadFile` does, but you only need to ensure that it returns the PEM encoded leaf certificate and the intermediate(s) (i.e. the one that's an "extra download"), concatenated in that order. tls.X509KeyPair builds the chain automatically.

Comment: I have attempted to not add the CAFile.pem as the RootCA also in my tls.config. But still, have the extra download required on my intermediate certification. I understand that you are saying the tls.X509KeyPair builds the chain automatically. The issue is that it is building it without the CAFile
Here is the certs.ReadFile.
// ReadFile returns a files contents as []byte from the filesystem, static or local
func (f *Files) ReadFile(filename string) ([]byte, error) {

 file, err := f.dir.Open(f.determinePath(filename))
 if err != nil {
  return nil, err
 }
return ioutil.ReadAll(file)
}

Comment: [Edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56632176/edit) if you want to add additional information. Don't put non-trivial code into comments, please. However, in this case it isn't important how ReadFile is implemented. Important is that it returns the complete chain and not just the leaf certificate. So simply concatenate /certs/website.com.pem and /certs/CAFile.pem and you should be done.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. My appologies, first time submitting question so a newb on this. So I agree that it is important that it returns the complete chain, but I am not sure how to add the CAFile.pem to the chain. It has no private key to pair it with... so that is where my confusion lies.

Comment: You don't need any key except the one for the leaf certificate. Just create one file with both certificates in it (or concatenate them in Go if that's easier for you; e.g. `tls.X509KeyPair(append(httpPem, caFilePem...), httpKey)`).